# How to properly phrase "can't fall back on anyone"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am in the process of asking for a salary adjustment.  I am trying to state in a letter that I am able to accomplish certain major tasks without being able to fall back on anyone for help.  Basically, I have a certain skill that I can't rely on any coworkers for because they don't posses this skill and there's no one else in my role.  How can I properly phrase this without being offensive to my boss, who doesn't have this skill?

I'm trying to demonstrate value by including this and am looking for a single sentence.

Comment: Is this for a cover letter to accompany a CV?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try any of the following terms:

- unassisted
- solely responsible for (task)
- without backup
- only resource for (task)
- single point of
  failure (although this could be considered to reflect negatively on
  your manager, as these are to be avoided in business)

I would probably chose 'solely responsible' since it emphasizes your positive attribute (responsibility for something important) more than the negative of your manager (failing for provide backup for something important).

Comment: Independently. Unique resource for . . .